# Auto-fill input field based on another input field angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, ngx-datatable

I have input field inside on ngx-data-table, when user update the value of input field, the another input field value needs to be auto field. Below is my code for my first input field

```
<ng-template *ngIf="col.name == 'comment' || col.label == 'comment'"
                     ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row"
                     let-group="group" let-rowHeight="rowHeight">
            <input autofocus
                   (blur)="updateValue($event, 'comment', rowIndex)"
                   type="text"
                   name="comment"
                   [value]="value" />
        </ng-template>
```

When user fill data on above input field, the below input field needs to be auto populated.

```
<ng-template *ngIf="col.name == 'discussion' || col.label == 'discussion'"
ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let row="row" >
<span [(ngModel)]="discussion">{{discussion}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

Here is my ts code

```
updateValue(event, cell, rowIndex)
    {
    console.log('inline editing rowIndex', rowIndex)
    this.editing[rowIndex + '-' + cell] = false;
    this.rows[rowIndex][cell] = event.target.value;
    this.discussion= [...this.rows];
    console.log('UPDATED!', this.discussion[rowIndex][cell]);
}
```

This code is not working correctly, giving error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'comment' of undefined".

I want when user update the value of input field, the another input field value needs to be auto field.

Please help or  any another way to achieve this.

Comment: you can  use two way binding to achive this

Comment: its not working, could you please share the working example, here is the reference  I have used http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#row-grouping

Comment: Seems like this.rows[rowIndex] in updateValue is undefined. Can you share whole code and also console log  this.rows[rowIndex]?

Comment: I am getting in console "inline editing rowIndex 0"